# No logro conexión remota a mi base de datos MySql

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Llevo ya algunos días peleandome con mi base de datos ya que no logro acceder remotamente a ella, al menos no desde PHP (de manera remota) ni desde Zapier (una api rest que estoy utilizando para hacer pruebas)

Dicha base de datos es mysql y está alojada en un VPS con Ubuntu.

Que ya he hecho?:

- Actualmente tengo desbloqueado el puerto 3306 desde el firewall
- También tengo desbloqueada la IP desde donde intento conectarme (en
  el firewall)
- En el archivo de configuración de mysql my.conf deshabilité la opción
  bind-address
- En mysql creé un usuario garantizando el acceso a la base de datos
  que quiero que se conecte con acceso a cualquier servidor (%)

Cabe destacar que la conexión local de la base de datos funciona excelentemente bien y las credenciales del usuario están correctas

y al final de todo esto, el mensaje que obtengo es:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No se puede establecer una conexi�n ya que el equipo de destino deneg� expresamente dicha conexi�n. in C:\xampp\htdocs\reportes_cercal\bootstrap_mode\login.php on line 6
Error, no se puede establecer conexion a la base de datos No se puede establecer una conexi�n ya que el equipo de destino deneg� expresamente dicha conexi�n.
```

Para esta conexión estoy utilizando el mismo código que utilizo para conectarme localmente via php.

Via remota php, evidentemente, cambiando los datos de conexion, es que me genera este error.

es decir en mi VPS tengo:

```
$db_server='localhost';
$db_username='usuario_local';
$db_pass='contraseña';
$db_database='mi_db';
```

y remotamente:

```
$db_server='la_ip_de_mi_vps';
$db_username='usuario_externo';
$db_pass='contraseña';
$db_database='mi_db';
```

No sé si estoy omitiendo algo, me falta un paso, configuré algo mal.

Si necesitan más información no duden en solicitarla.

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113314/discussion-on-question-by-adel-azeroth-no-logro-conexion-remota-a-mi-base-de-dat).